# How to mask in Illustrator then use in After Affects aswell

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, animation, mask, adobe-after-effects

I am trying to do this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z58VpFg30k.
Basically it has a circle and uses a mask to create holes in it and animate it.
I was wondering if I could import circles from illustrator with masks over it and animate it as well. If so could someone tell me how I can make the mask in Illustrator as well which I can animate in AE. Thank you

Comment: Welcome! :) You can simply copy and paste it to a layer you want.

Comment: So in Illustrator instead of making a mask, make a layer then in AE convert it into a mask?